# Ionic 2 virtual scroll with objects

Tags: json, ionic2

I'm building an Ionic 2 app where I want to list users so they can find each other. Since there can be 1500 users in my app, I wanted to use virtual scroll. With a string array the virtual scroll is working perfectly. Array:

```
users = ["hi", "bye"]
```

This is the code in my html page:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="users" approxItemHeight="50px">
  <ion-item *virtualItem="let user">
    {{user}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Now I'm creating an array of json objects, the array looks like this:

```
users = [
   {
     displayName: "foo",
     email: "foo@bar.nl",
     picture: "assets/img/defaultAvatar.png",
     username: "foo"
   },
   {
     displayName: "bar",
     email: "bar@foo.nl",
     picture: "assets/img/defaultAvatar.png",
     username: "bar"
   }
]
```

Then I adjust the code in my html, like I would do in a regular list

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="users" approxItemHeight="50px">
  <ion-item *virtualItem="let user">
      user.displayName: {{user.displayName}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Problem: I get an empty list, while printing users on my page displays an array of json objects. With *ngFor I'm able to create a list for the exact same dataset. There's not much documentation for the virtual scroll, so I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an other problem, related to retrieving data from server, meaning the virtual scroll got initialized with an empty array.

[Github issue: virtual scroll not refreshing on empty initialization](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/11532)